# Best glue option for laminated Kevlar <> birch plywood for not peeling off

Tags: wood, adhesive, carbon-fiber, epoxy

I have a problem where I glue a laminated sheet of Kevlar to birch plywood and it peels off easily

I tried:

- Laminating the Kevlar directly on the plywood with lamenting epoxy
- Using the laminating epoxy to glue Kevlar (with peel ply surface) to the plywood

Both options are peeling off and I need a strong bond

Any recommendations?

Comment: I'd see if a good marine epoxy like West System can do it. It is expensive tho. For peeling, surface prep is essential.

Comment: I expect it is peeling the plywood off itself. Where did you get you plywood from and what are the specs and industry certification of it. Please explain what the panel is for, what the load cases are for it, what the laminate schedule is, and what the ply skin laminate thickness is. If you use $300/sheet plywood, you'll probably get a better result. You may need to bond a layer of S glass to the plywood with epoxy to get the peel resistance you need. It basically comes down to laminate thickness and stiffness, And thickness is the easy way to get stiffness.

Comment: To maximize what you have, try the following. Heat soak the plywood for a day at 80F. It needs to be bone dry as well. Mix some laminating epoxy at 70F or cooler and apply two thin coats to the plywood. The second coat goes on when the first is green but tack free. You need the temps slowly dropping the entire time.  So you end up at around 60F after the second coat is tack free. You want at least 5 mil of epoxy fill. Now drape your fabric and wet out and fill with two or three more coats of laminating resin.